# Ruby I/O programming about a unless loop

Tags: ruby, io

As a tutorial from http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/io/

```
file = File.open("sample.txt", 'r')
while !file.eof?
   line = file.readline
   puts line
end
```

this method puts every line, however when I replaced

```
while !file.eof?
```

with

```
unless file.eof?
```

the loop only runs once, so why?

Comment: Just a note that the conventional way of writing that is `File.foreach("sample.txt"') { |line| puts line }`. Among other things, [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) closes the file before returning. (Your code requires `file.close` at the end.) You may write `File.foreach...`, rather than `IO.foreach...` because `File.superclass #=> IO`. Note from the doc that `foreach` returns an enumerator when invoked without a block. That allows you to chain it to `Enumerable` methods (e.g., `File.foreach(fname).with_object({}) { |line,h| .... }`, which can be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`unless`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-unless) is the negative equivalent of `if`. It does not loop.

The keyword you were looking for, presumably, is [`until`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-until) - which is the inverse of `while`, so does indeed perform a loop.

Comment: A million thanks for you!
I just start learning programming and i know little about these basic concept. Now i understand the difference between "until" and "unless".